# Setting header for only one uitableview

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I need help. I have three `UITableViews` in one `UIView`. However, I only want one `UITableView` to have a header. How can I say it in code? I already have the following code. Thanks guys.

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {   
    if (tableView == Table1) {
        return @"My Header Text";
    } else if (tableView == Table2) {
        return nil;
    } else if (tableView == Table3) {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Comment: plz send your UITableView code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If that's not working you could also try to return zeroes for header's heights as well:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (tableView == Table1) 
    {
        return 50.0; // or what's the height?
    } 
    else
    {
         return 0.0;
    }
}
```

Comment: Check R.A's answer (+1 from me), it beetter to solve your problem like this.

Comment: But then, how can i make it stay to its position., i mean, it drags along when i scroll..

Comment: @user2234264 This will work, but it's not good. I've just generated a solution among others for provided code and level. And that's easier to copy-paste. But for sure not good if I understand the situation right.

Comment: @user2234264 You want it to be always visible (and somehow attached to the scroll, i.e. it scrolls with the cells but don't go off from screen)?

Comment: Then single tableView section and a header for that section. TableView's header will not always be on screen.

Answer (score 2):

The code you provided will be **add a header view for a certain section only.** So If you have two or more section then you need to write extra logic to set the header view for each section.

Here it is an easy way to set the `tableHeaderView` for single table is.

```
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
label.text = @"my table header";
table1.tableHeaderView = label;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
NSString *sectionTitle = [self tableView:tableView titleForHeaderInSection:section];
if (sectionTitle == nil) {
return nil;
}
 UILabel *label = [[[UILabel alloc] init] autorelease];
 label.frame = CGRectMake(20, 6, 300, 30);
 label.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 label.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:16];
 label.text = sectionTitle;

  UIView *view = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, SectionHeaderHeight)];
  [view addSubview:label];
  return view;
  }
```

Comment: This could not work in iOS 5+, as far as "Prior to iOS 5.0, table views would automatically resize the heights of headers to 0 for sections where tableView:viewForHeaderInSection: returned a nil view. In iOS 5.0 and later, you must return the actual height for each section header in this method."